# PhpStorm - Change theme for remote server view

Tags: themes, phpstorm, phpstorm-2018.1

In PhpStorm is there a way to theme remote connection files differently to local project files?

When open they are very similar looking to each other and sometimes it's easy to work on 1 view when I am meant to be working on the other!

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "remote connection files" exactly? How does it look for you now?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Remote connection files are FTP files (Tools > Deployment > Browse Remote Host). As you can see from this screen shot: https://i.imgur.com/Xj39g8S.png both files look almost identical and it's easy to incorrectly edit the wrong one. It would be good to be able to change the theme for remote files so they look different when viewed next to local files.

Comment: So .. you do **Remote Edit** .. when editing remote file directly without downloading it into your project first (technically it's downloaded anyway, but stored outside of the project in a temp file). You should be able to recognize them already -- it has a big "REMOTE" text on a tab name (must be your Connection name). I'm not sure if it's possible to do anything about this here, need to play around with this myself (never had a need to do remote edit; it's a bad practice in my workflow).

Comment: Yes it was me that named the connection "REMOTE" to try to help distinguish the 2. Ok. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot change editor background or stuff like that to make it more visible in actual editor area.

But ... from what I see IDE already uses different background colour for the *editor tab* (the tab itself). It's not that visible there on your screenshot because you are using Darcula GUI theme where you do not see much contrast in colours used.

You can change that at `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | File Colors`: choose more suitable for you colour for **"Non-Project Files" scope** (e.g. use bright red or blue -- whatever suits your theme and your preferences). Also double check that `Use in Editor Tabs` option is checked (should be already).

**Please note** that this will apply to *any non-project files* (i.e. even excluded or outside of the project root).

[image]

---

Another thing: in recent IDE versions (2018.2 is the latest stable ATM) the file edited remotely will have additional bar at the top of the editor with Compare / Revert | Upload and possibly other actions .. so it should be even more noticeable that you're editing remote file.

Comment: Awesome! (Almost) Exactly what I was trying to achieve. Thanks!